# How to submit asp.net form data using jquery ajax feature

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax

dear all i want to know how to submit asp.net form data using jquery ajax functionality and how im get that json data in the server side

?

Comment: Dear you ... **this is not a Generate-Code Forum**, shows us what have you tried, what have you tested and **then** we will help you with some code if you're stuck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="#" id="example-form">

...

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#example-form').submit(function(){

        // block form

        $.post('putUrlHere', $('#example-form').serialize(), function(data) {
            //call back happens here.  Unblock form/show result
        });

        return false; // this prevents regular post, forcing ajax post.

    });

</script>
```

**REFERENCE :**  http://forums.asp.net/t/1611677.aspx/1?Jquery+with+ASP+NET+Form+submit

Otherwise Check : jquery + ajax combine..... 
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

Comment: Thanks sikender but how can i grab the client side para meters from server side

Comment: i want to know how can i call specific asp.net server method from jquery and how can i grab that parameters?

Comment: you can use json for calling webmethod.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#<%=btnSubmit.ClientID %>").click(
  function()
  {
    $.ajax
    ({
         type: "POST",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         url: "Default.aspx/AcceptFormData",
         data: "{'funcParam':'"+$('#formName').serialize()+"'}",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(msg)
         {
              var msgFromASPXFunction = msg.d
         }
     });
  }
 );
});


[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string AcceptFormData(string funcParam)
{
  // this is your server side function
  //the data you will get will be in format e.g. a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4&e=5 inside funcParam variable
  return "Data Submitted";

}
```

Just note the server-side function name should match the parameter you specified in the url property of $.ajax function of jQuery. (In above case it is "AcceptFormData"

Also the parameter name should be same as of the server side function parameter. In this case it is "funcParam".

Just compare the $.ajax and server-side function in this code.

Regards,

Amin Sayed

(Note: Please mark if it is helpful)

Comment: Thank you a lot For your Post could you please Explain me Below Code Fraction  data: "{'funcParam':'"+$('#formName').serialize()+"'}",

Comment: This is a parameter to your C# function passed from the javascript, whenever you try to call the Ajax (in this case at the time you submit). You can see 'funcParam' name matches the parameter of your C# function AcceptFormData. You need to make sure these two match.